# "You need to be logged in to view that page" alert for authenticated user

Tags: users

I have created a page using hook_menu for "employee" role using the code below:

```
 $items['admin/employee'] = array(
    'title' => 'Dashboard - Employee',
    'page callback' => 'employee_page',
    'access arguments' => array('Access administration theme'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

When this page is viewed by an employee this alert appears: "You need to be logged in to view that page".

I tried to rebuild cache etc.

PS. I don't have an issue to access this page as an admin. Maybe I should use different access arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, checking access as user 1 or Administrator is not a test because no permission checks are done for user 1, and in most cases Administrators have all permissions.

Two, your permission is mixed case, change it to all lower case and clear the cache.

Three, in order to access anything under `/admin`, user will also need `access administration pages` permission as well - or whatever permission is assigned on that menu item (I think that’s the one).